# SignalR causing IIS and VS hanging

Tags: signalr

I just started using SignalR (latest 2.0.3) on project running latest IIS and Visual Studio 2013.

I noticed an issue where sometimes the web page just hangs trying to load for an abnormal amount of time (never actually loads).

When this happens, I go into Visual Studio and hit the square to stop debugging, and visual studio starts to hang (not that it freezes VS but just loading symbol trying to stop debugging never actually stops debugging)

I realized the solution is to stop IIS which immediately causes the page to load and visual studio to respond and stop debugging. Start IIS and it's back to normal but this has occured multiple times already.

Answer (score 4):

When this happens, try checking the current requests in IIS (go to Worker Processes in the IIS server features view and double-click the App Pool of your website) and I suspect you'll find 10 of them in process. This can happen because IIS on Win7/Win8 is limited to 10 concurrent requests and depending on your app, signalR could be using all of them up. and once all of those requests are used up, new requests will hang.

You can also kill them requests by recycling the App Pool.